# Makefile not using include/library paths?

Tags: c++, include, makefile

Well, after 3 hours of researching, I'm about to go insane, so I figure it's time to pass it off to some new eyes.

```
CXXFLAGS        = -g -Wall
OBJS            = main.o
PROG            = test
INCLUDES        = -I /usr/include/mysql -I /usr/local/include
LIBS            = -L /usr/lib/mysql -l libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0 -L /usr/local/lib -l libmysqlpp.so.3.1.0

all:            $(PROG)

${PROG}:        $(OBJS)
            $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

clean:;         $(RM) -f $(PROG) core *.o
```

There's something wrong with the include paths, because I get errors that mysql_version.h does not exist when it clearly does exist in /usr/include/mysql.

Checking the first part out of the ouput, it says

```
g++ -g -Wall   -c -o main.o main.cpp
```

which makes me think that I've formatted something in the Makefile wrong (due to the extra spaces and lack of include/library paths). However, I've looked at dozens of manuals and articles on Makefiles and the g++ options and... no progress.

I assume this should be a simple fix. Please, please help (do you sense my despair?).

On another note, do you think specifying the library specifically is necessary? I had this stuff running in XCode just fine, but I'm trying to migrate the code to my web server... the Makefile has stopped all progress, and I figure it's something I should learn from.

Comment: Works ok on my Mac. Though it complained about using Tab and not spaces (which make is particular about). sorry can't be of more help :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your makefile, you have added your include directives to the linking stage, not the compiling stage.

The lines

```
${PROG}:        $(OBJS)
            $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

Say to make the program in ${PROG} from object files in ${OBJS} by calling the compiler in ${CXX} passing the include folders (along with your other arguments).  Instead, for your variable section, do this:

```
INCLUDES        = -I /usr/include/mysql -I /usr/local/include
CXXFLAGS        = -g -Wall ${INCLUDES}
OBJS            = main.o
PROG            = test
LIBS            = -L /usr/lib/mysql -l libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0 -L /usr/local/lib -l libmysqlpp.so.3.1.0
```

This way your CXXFLAGS (which are used for the compile stage) should now pickup your include directives.

Comment: You're right, I missed that part when I tried it. I only looked at the link stage. Good spot.

Comment: I think that `-I` is generally used for pre-compiler step, so it would better fit `CPPFLAGS`, but `CXXFLAGS` is fine as well. +1